# Laravel 4 having difficult time tracking location of a method

Tags: php, laravel-4

I'm using PHPStorm if it has methods that help, I'm on a Mac OSX system also.

we have the following line in our code:

```
$config = Config::get('regions');
```

First, I want to find the location of `class Config`.  Well, this won't work..

```
print_r(get_class(Config));
```

So I do this:

```
$test = new Config; //works
print_r(get_class(Config));
```

Which gives me:

```
\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config
```

Which in turn is very short:

```
<?php namespace Illuminate\Support\Facades;

/**
 * @see \Illuminate\Config\Repository
 */
class Config extends Facade {

    /**
     * Get the registered name of the component.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected static function getFacadeAccessor() { return 'config'; }

}
```

So.. I look in `Facade`, and there **is** no `get()` method.

Doing a search for `function get(..` in the code, there are over 100+ instances of this.

How in the world can I find this specific `get()` method?

Comment: And why you need it? This method just returns content from file regions.php from app/config folder.

Comment: Although I appreciate the contribution, that wasn't the question I asked.  And in some case in the future, some developer (like myself) might have wanted to know how to locate a specific method, or some other specific method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel uses Facades to provide a static interface. Basically they are shortcuts for objects & variables which are in the service container.

Check out [Laravel 4.2 Facades documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/facades)

What Laravel does is allowing you to use a static call:

```
Config::get('x');
```

And it resolves it from the service container under the key provided by the Facade class. For Config this is `'config'`.

In Laravel 5.4 it is registered to the container in: 
src/Illuminate/Foundation/start.php

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Register The Configuration Repository
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| The configuration repository is used to lazily load in the options for
| this application from the configuration files. The files are easily
| separated by their concerns so they do not become really crowded.
|
*/

$app->instance('config', $config = new Config(

    $app->getConfigLoader(), $env

));
```

And you'll notice this in the same file:

```
use Illuminate\Config\Repository as Config;
```

So the class you are looking for is `Illuminate\Config\Repository` which has the `get()` method.

Which is also what the Facade itself hints too ;)

```
/**
 * @see \Illuminate\Config\Repository
 */
```

---

Some of the Facades are handled within the framework, others are provided by ServiceProviders in the application itself, from which you can find which class they bind to the container.

Comment: Thanks.  I did see the @see hint but for some reason (probably user error :) I didn't find the `get()` method, probably looking in the wrong place I am sure.